# Magneto 2.4.6-p3 products not showing in catalog or search

Tags: catalog, products, search, magento2.4.6

I have seen this question asked so many different ways and for various Magento versions.  I've spun up **Magento 2.4.6-p3** and after bringing up the frontend and checking the admin backend, I don't get any errors, not with Elasticsearch either.  I am able to add products to the catalog and verify all of the recommended settings there, double check my indexing and cache-flush.  The products will not show in the front end.  Not on any category page I add them to.  I can manually enter the product URL, bring the item up, and add it to a cart, but it is not showing on the frontend.  My search also does not bring that search product up.  I have read through dozens of suggestions and attempted them all several times.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please confirm your product's salable quantity is not 0 ?
Are  you able to see the product's salable quantity is updating according to  product quantity ?

Comment: Also, check if you have not introduced any custom attribute with wrong properties for example Text type attribute cannot be used in layered navigation by default. You cannot do that via admin but if you create such attribute via script then Magento doesn't stop you. I did that once and took me 3 whole day to find the problem lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of issue you may need to check few points -

1. What search you are using? If it is Elasticsearch, check if "Test Connection" is success. If Live search check if products are listing in graphql tab of live-search setting.
2. If B2B is enabled along with "Shared Catalog". Then check if products are assigned to correct shared catalog.
3. If Category Permissions is enabled, check if the product display permissions are set to display or not.
4. Check if the correct websites is assigned to the products.
5. If MSI is enabled and setup, check if proper source and stock is assigned to the product.
6. It can be a re-indexer issue, try running indexer.
7. Check if there is any error log.

Comment: The responses were very helpful!  When I created a configurable product, an issue was occuring where the stock qty was not updating and being left at 0. I could manually go in and change every.single product but this was not a good or right solution. I ended up rebuilding everything and reinstalling 2.4.6. It worked after that, so I really never found the problem.